# Shift a image within a Frame in an Android Layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I design a Android Layout where only a cropped part of an Image should be displayed within a frame. I do this with an ImageView within an RelativeLayout. The ImageView lies below the RelativeLayout and is larger than the RelativeLayout. The ImageView is set android:scaleType="centerCrop".
Now I need to shift the Image behind the Frame (the RelativeLayout) in order to display another part of it inside the Frame.  How is this possible? A setY() on the ImageView shift the cropped Image, but the Image should first be shifted and cropped afterwards.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried paddingbottom for imageview?

paddingtop makes image to occupy less height and it gets center cropped in remaining portion

you can align you imageview with relative layout and can show rest of the view